# Convert Image to Pdf using itextsharp with spacing on top

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Im doing a image to pdf program.

I want to set the size of the image as the size of the pdf and a extra space on top with 50

i tried this code

```
                using (var imageStream = new FileStream(imagelocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var image = Image.GetInstance(imageStream);

                    Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(image.Width, image.Height), 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(pdfOutput, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                        document.Open();
                        document.Add(image);
                        document.Close();
                    }
                }
```

but the problem is it doesn't have a top margin,

when i try this code

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(image.Width, image.Height), 0, 50, 50, 0);
```

it crop a part of the image for the space. how can i make this work?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the document margins like "0, 50, 50, 0" you are also setting a margin-right, that might not be what you want in this case. The margin top is the correct way to get some space above the image.
Alternatively you can add some empty lines to your document before adding  the image, e.g.: document.Add(new Paragraph(Chunk.NewLine))

You can use image.ScaleToFit() and pass in something like document.PageSize.Height and document.PageSize.Width to make that image fit your page.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution. i didn't realize that this simple code will work

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(image.Width, image.Height + 150), 0, 0, 150, 0);
```